# Does column with lot of data cause issue

Tags: sql, performance

I have a table with say 10 columns and 3 of them have textFields that has some Html in them, now because of these 3 fields row size increases resulting in increase of size of datatable to more than 4GB.

My question is whether these field where we are storing large data affect performance of the application, these columns aren't there in joins but have there place in table.

Will normalizing them improve performance of application?

I have to take it to senior colleagues, but before I go to them with the suggestion just wanted to know if someone has tried doing so and whether or not it worked

Comment: Yes, minimally, usually.  Those fields in the row data are actually just stored as a 16 byte pointer to the real data.  The real data can however impact full table scans because the data is now more scattered, but that depends on your queries, the size of the resultsets, etc. In my experience, separating the data out was not worth the meager performance gains.

Comment: It depends on database engine (what do you use?) and queries that you running.

Answer (score 2):

A properly implemented database (PostgreSQL, for instance) would only store a limited amount of data directly in the table, where it could affect performance. The remainder is stored separately, keeping only a reference, of maybe the starting fragment directly in the table. Hence the impact on search performance may not be very big. Of course, when you retrieve the data, reading really large column surely will not be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same problem with one of table but I solved my problem to create indexes and separate out table . please learn about indexes and normalization there are many way to handle this.
Thanks.

Comment: there is already clustered index in place, what I am trying to find is should I consider normalizing because of large data in column, else it would be waste of effort

Comment: please separate your large data column with new table and then try.

Answer (score 0):

You can only know if you try it out. In principle if you have proper indexes in the tables, it should be all fine. But it depends on your particular RDBMS implementation.

Comment: I have to put it in front of my senior colleague, but before I go to them with the suggestion just wanted to know if someone has tried doing so and whether or not it worked.

Comment: @VinayPandey, in theory separating the table might even be slower because you would have additionally at least one index and a foreign index. It also depends on how are you doing queries. For example do you do `select *` or select individual columns. If you get `*` then you will be retrieving more data than in the case when you have the table split.
In any case splitting the table (even if it helps) sounds like a micro-optimization that at some point may become just a complication. You most probably can get better results using caching or optimizing queries or something else higher level.